# Single regex to remove HTML tags and also the remaining whitespace

Tags: html, regex, tags, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I have a group of colors in an unordered list.  It contains miscellaneous whitespace and line breaks:

```
<li>blue</li><li>red</li>
<li>yellow</li>
<li>green </li><li>orange</li>
<li>purple</li><li>brown</li><li>black</li>
```

Using `str.replace('<.+?>', ' ')`, I get:

```
blue  red 
yellow 
green   orange 
purple  brown  black
```

Is it possible to incorporate whitespace removal (a la `'\s+'`) in the original regex without running it through a second regex?

I want the data like this:

```
blue red yellow green orange purple brown black
```

I know about the precautions of modifying HTML with regex, but this will be an isolated string sent to another app.

Comment: How about replacing `<.+?>|\s+` with a single space character `' '`?

Comment: @dvo That still leaves multiple spaces between words. Each tag creates a space that could lead to repeated whitespace. `⁃blue⁃⁃red⁃⁃⁃yellow⁃⁃⁃green⁃⁃⁃orange⁃⁃⁃purple⁃⁃brown⁃⁃black⁃`

Answer (score 1):

```
var stripedHtml = htmlString.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

or iterate over all tags and get them textContent

Comment: Your regex does not remove line breaks and does not retain a single space between words.

Comment: @Tony, yes, you are right. Remove spaces stripedHtml.trim(), Since there may be colors, for example: light green.

Answer (score 1):

This should have the desired affect.

```
str.replace(/(\s*<.*?>\s*)+/g, ' ').trim()
```

The parentheses create a search group, so having a + after the group says match one or more of this group.

The \s* before and after each tag is redundant for the example shown, but I'm assuming other tags are liable to have whitespace before or after the content of the tag such as in:

```html
<li>green </li>
```

The first and final tag replaced by a space will result in extra space before and after so we trim() to remove that.

Comment: Thanks, this is really close, but as you stated, I still get spaces at the start and end of the string. I need to keep this as a regex only... I can't change the code to add a trim.